# How to properly install PySide into relocatable virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyside

I'm pip installing PySide into a virtualenv:

```
sudo virtualenv --always-copy $VENV
source $VENV/bin/activate
sudo $VENV/bin/pip install pyside
sudo $VENV/bin/python $VENV/bin/pyside_postinstall.py -install
deactivate
```

The virtualenv works great and I can run my Python/PySide script without problems:

```
$VENV/bin/python $SCRIPT
```

Now, I make my virtualenv relocatable:

```
virtualenv --relocatable $VENV
```

I move it:

```
mv $VENV $VENV_RELOCATED
```

...and again run my script:

```
source $VENV_RELOCATED/bin/activate
$VENV_RELOCATED/bin/python $SCRIPT
```

This time around, I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtUiTools
ImportError: dlopen(/absolute/path/to/relocated_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpyside-python2.7.1.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /absolute/path/to/relocated_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/QtCore.so
  Reason: image not found
```

These are the contents of the script:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtUiTools
```

Please note: the absolute path printed twice in the error message is the $VENV_RELOCATED

This is all on OS X 10.11.0 with Python 2.7.10 and PySide 1.2.2.

**Question: How should I properly install PySide into a relocatable virtualenv?**

Comment: Just a question why do you need `sudo` in the first place?

Comment: `sudo` is required for `virtualenv --always-copy`. I've also tried to not use `sudo` and convert symlinks into files manually. This works fine but still produce the PySide error I need help with.

Comment: Can you clarify? I can run `virtualenv-3.4 --always-copy test` and it runs fine. Sounds like there is something missing from the question.

Comment: Sure. This is what happens if I don't use `sudo`: https://gist.github.com/fredrikaverpil/e9ea365a0235fb8cb0a1 – However, I would rather focus on getting PySide working inside a relocatable virtualenv.

Comment: The point of `virtualenv` is that you should never need to use `sudo`. Maybe something is wrong with your file system and you have messed up your file permissions by running some command earlier with `sudo`?

Comment: Or you are just running the command in wrong folder.

Comment: No, permissions of the folder I'm running inside are fine. As you can see from the [gist](https://gist.github.com/fredrikaverpil/e9ea365a0235fb8cb0a1), shutil is not permitteed to copy files from within the Python Framework to the virtualenv without `sudo`. I actually think that's intended on OS X as these files are `-rw-r--r--` in the framework location. With all due respect, I don't think this is related to answering my original question and solving the problem I'm having.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91186/discussion-between-fredrik-and-mikko-ohtamaa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the next PySide release (probably tagged "1.2.3" when released) has this fixed: https://github.com/PySide/PySide/issues/129

However, I also made PySide 1.2.2 work inside a relocatable virtualenv on OS X 10.11 (El Capitan). For this, I modified the `localize_libpaths()` function in the $VIRTUALENV/bin/pyside_postinstall.py script.

Patch details: If a virtualenv is detected when the script is executed, it will not use `@rpath`. Instead it will use `@executable_path` and search relatively from the python binary in the virtualenv. Since the PySide module is always installed in the same place within a virtualenv, I thought this should work in all scenarios.

```
def localize_libpaths(libpath, local_libs, enc_path=None):
    """ Set rpaths and install names to load local dynamic libs at run time

    Use ``install_name_tool`` to set relative install names in `libpath` (as
    named in `local_libs` to be relative to `enc_path`.  The default for
    `enc_path` is the directory containing `libpath`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    libpath : str
        path to library for which to set install names and rpaths
    local_libs : sequence of str
        library (install) names that should be considered relative paths
    enc_path : str, optional
        path that does or will contain the `libpath` library, and to which the
        `local_libs` are relative.  Defaults to current directory containing
        `libpath`.
    """
    if enc_path is None:
        enc_path = abspath(dirname(libpath))
    install_names = osx_get_install_names(libpath)
    need_rpath = False
    for install_name in install_names:
        if install_name[0] in '/@':
            continue
        if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix'):
            # virtualenv detected - use @executable_path
            back_tick('install_name_tool -change %s @executable_path/../lib/python2.7/site-packages/PySide/%s %s' %
               (install_name, install_name, libpath))
        else:
            # not a virtualenv - use @rpath
            back_tick('install_name_tool -change %s @rpath/%s %s' %
               (install_name, install_name, libpath))
            need_rpath = True
    if need_rpath and enc_path not in osx_get_rpaths(libpath):
        back_tick('install_name_tool -add_rpath %s %s' %
           (enc_path, libpath))
```

On Windows, there are no issues with relocating a virtualenv with PySide in it. However, For Linux I have not managed to find a solution. I guess waiting for PySide 1.2.3 is the way to go here.